# Ether.js BigNumber doesn't work with slug

Tags: next.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js, ethers.js

I am building an app where I need to fetch a NFT on a market place. I use Next.js and a slug to do so. The page is : nfts/[id].js. I have a function getMarketItem() that works fine when I use a hardcoded number or string, but doesn't work with the id from the slug whenever I refresh the page.

I get what I expect with getMarketItem(1), but if I use getMarketItem(id) I get an error :

> Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=undefined,
> code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.5.0)

There are no problem with the slug, when I console.log(id) I get the correct number. I also tried with Number(id), or with string and nothing works. I get the same error when I try to do : BigNumber.from(id), so I believe that the error is really coming from there.

My JS code :

```
export default function CardNft({id}) {

  const [nft, setNft] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    loadNFT()
  }, [])

    async function loadNFT() {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider()
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(marketplaceAddress, NFTMarketplace.abi, provider)
                
    **const data = await contract.getMarketItem(id)** /the problem is here
        const tokenUri = await contract.tokenURI(data.tokenId)
        const meta = await axios.get(tokenUri)
        let price = ethers.utils.formatUnits(data.price.toString(), 'ether')
        let item = {
            price,
            tokenId: data.tokenId,
            seller: data.seller,
            owner: data.owner,
            image: meta.data.image,
            name: meta.data.name,
            description: meta.data.description,
        }
    setNft(item)

      
    }
  return (...) }
```

My Solidity code (I tried two different functions) :

```
function getMarketItem(uint256 marketItemId) public view returns (MarketItem memory) {
  return idToMarketItem[marketItemId];
}

function fetchMarketItem(uint itemId) public view returns (MarketItem memory) {
  MarketItem memory item = idToMarketItem[itemId];
  return item;
}
```

Do you know how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `loadNFT` in useEffect so when you call it, I think "id" is not defined yet. Add Id to dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
    loadNFT()
  }, [id])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I just had to pass the ID as an argument in the function :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    loadNFT(id)
  }, [id])
  
    async function loadNFT(nftid) {
    /* create a generic provider and query for unsold market items */
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider()
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(marketplaceAddress, NFTMarketplace.abi, provider)
    try{const data = await contract.fetchMarketItem(nftid)
    ...
```